# Evaluate integral of $x^3dy \wedge dz+y^3dz \wedge dx+z^3 dx \wedge dy$ over the upper hemisphere.

Tags: calculus, integration, stokes-theorem

Calculate the integral of the differential form $\omega$ over the half-sphere $S^{+}$, where:

- $\omega = x^3 dy \wedge dz + y^3 dz \wedge dx + z^3 dx \wedge dy $
- $S^{+} = \Big\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \big| x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1, z \geq 0 \Big\}$

We have such orientation of $S^{+}$ that vector $[0,0,1]$ is normal in point $(0,0,1)$.

We can use Stokes' theorem to calculate the integral of the differential form over half-sphere with circle on the bottom (because we need to calculate a closed solid), we can call it $A$. Then we can subtract the bottom, let's call it $B$ (it should be easy to calculate the bottom - it's just a circle). We have that:

$$\int_{\partial A} \omega = \int_{A} d\omega =  \int_{S^{+}} \omega +  \int_{B} \omega$$

\begin{align}d \omega &= d(x^3 dy \wedge dz + y^3 dz \wedge dx + z^3 dx \wedge dy)\\ &= d x^3 dy \wedge dz + d y^3 dz \wedge dx + d z^3 dx \wedge dy\\ &= 3x^2 dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + 3y^2 dy \wedge dz \wedge dx + 3z^2 dz \wedge dx \wedge dy\\ &= 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz\end{align}

First I calculate the whole solid:

\begin{align}\int_{A} d\omega &= \int_{A} 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) dx \wedge dy \wedge dz\\ &= 3 \int_{A} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 d^3(x,y,z)\\ &= 3 \int_0^1 \int_{( x^2 + y^2 < 1 - z^2 )} x^2 + y^2 + z^2 d^2(x,y)  dz\\ &=
 3 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}(1 - z^2)^2 + z^2(1 - z^2) dz\\ &= 3 \int_0^1 1 - 2z^2 + z^4 + z^2 - z^4 dz\\ &= 3 \int_0^1 1 - z^2 dz\\ &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}= \frac{1}{6}\end{align}

Then I would like to calculate the circle - I know that $z = 0 \implies dz = 0$, but then I get:

$\int_{B} \omega = \int_{(x^2 + y^2 < 1)} 0 + 0 + z^3 dx \wedge dy = 0$

Why is that? I thought that it should be just $\pi$ (since I evaluate area of a circle with radius $= 1$) but I don't get anything.

Having $\int_{B} \omega = 0$ I would get:
$$\int_{\partial A} \omega = \int_{S^{+}} \omega = \frac{1}{6}$$

Any idea what do I do wrong?

Comment: In the future please format equations better using `\begin{align}` etc. and avoid blank lines in math mode. You should have seen that the whole solid calculation was just a mess. Curly brackets are `\{` and `\}`. Hint : grab a post that has what you are trying to render and click on edit to see how they've dunnit.

Comment: Your integrals over $S^+$ should be $\int_{S^+}\omega$ not $\int_{S^+}\color{red}{d}\omega\,.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From
\begin{align}\tag{1}
&\iiint\limits_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz
=\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} r^2\,r^2\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi\,dr\\
&\quad\quad =\Big(\int_0^1r^4\,dr\Big)\,(2\pi)\,2=\frac{4\pi}{5}
\end{align}
we see
$$\tag{2}
\int_Ad\omega=\iiint\limits_{\scriptstyle x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1\atop \scriptstyle z\ge 0}3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{6\pi}{5}
$$
because this integral must be half of $4\pi/5$ times $3\,.$

Proof. Use the symmetry of the integrand in (1) and the integration region
under $z\mapsto -z\,.$

To get
$$
\int_{S^+}\omega
$$
you use ***Gauss'*** theorem (not Stokes') by which
$$\tag{3}
\int_{\partial A}\omega =\int_{S^+}\omega\color{red}{-}\underbrace{\int_B\omega}_{(*)}=\int_A\,d\omega=\frac{6\pi}{5}.
$$
The missing piece is  (*) over $B=\{x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ which should not be that hard to calculate. The minus is important because we must orient $B$
such that the normal vector points out of $A\,.$

In this case however you are correct that
$$
\int_B\omega=0
$$
because only the $dx\wedge dy$ term contributes and there $z^3$ is zero.

There is nothing wrong with this. We have a vector field
$$
F=\begin{pmatrix}x^3\\y^3\\z^3\end{pmatrix}
$$
that has no flux through $B\,.$ Therefore, all the flux created by the divergence must get out of $A$ through the upper hemisphere.

To further address the comments:

- Orientation again: in
  $$
  \int_B\dots dx\wedge dy
  $$
  the normal vector at points of $B$ points upward (positive $z$ direction) but Gauss wants that we let it point downward. Hence the minus sign
  in (3). To memorize this you take for $\partial A$ a cube and a
  constant (hence divergence free) vector field. If you had no minus sign
  between the integrals of two opposite faces your fluxes would add up instead of becoming zero together.
- There is no "right" coordinate system. Due to the change of variables formula all of them must give the same result. The choice of the coordinate system is pure convenience. Being a good circus horse I shall do it now  in cylindrical coordinates:
  \begin{align}
  \int_Ad\omega&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi} 3(\rho^2+z^2)\,\rho\,d\varphi\,d\rho\,dz\\&=6\pi\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}(\rho^3+z^2\rho)\,d\varphi\,d\rho\,dz\\
  &=6\pi\int_0^1\frac{(1-z^2)^2}{4}+\frac{z^2(1-z^2)}{2}\,dz=\frac{6\pi}{5}\tag{4}
  \end{align}
  as it must.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps a lot (I think there may be a small mistake, after "we see" under integral there should be $z \geq 0$, not $z \geq 1$, right?). I have a question - would that "technique of scaling" work for any $\omega$ or do we use the fact that function $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is in some sense symmetric when conbined with the ball $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$? I mean, it would not be true that for any other function $\omega$ taking half of ball would yield the result of half of value of the integral for whole ball, right?

Comment: Also, about orientating B in such way that the normal vector points out of A - I think that if I value $S^{+}$ as positive (in same orientation as the 'normaln ball' in $\mathbb{R}^2$), then B soulf be negative, right? Just by looking at right hand rule I see that when I cut the ball, as I move with my right palm, the vector that is normal and pointing outside on the bottom is not the same as the vector on $S^{+}$.

Comment: And the last thing - in the book that I found that problem in they said that it can be solved using some theorem or in more classic way, with change of coordinates. They said to use cylinder coordinates: $(\phi, z) \rightarrow (x = \sqrt{1 - z^2} \cos(\phi), y = \sqrt{1 - z^2} \sin(\phi), z = z)$ and calculate pullback. But you used spherical coordiates. Why is that then the case that in this problem both systems of coordinates can be used to solve it? Usually I thought that there may be only $1$ system of coordinates that would be "the right fit" for solving an integral of that type.

Comment: Could you please answer my questions? @Kurt G.

Comment: @mathman12 See the edit.

Comment: The reason why cylinder coordinates and spherical coordinates makes no difference is the fact that the map is 1d: $ z = cos \theta,    dz = \sin \theta d\theta$. The wedge-algebra is the same and the cylindrical coordinates have the advantage for surface integrals that the sphere has constant surface area per dz, see the simple formula $  2 * (2\ \pi)$

Comment: @RolandF I don't see a direct calculation of surface integrals in that answer. Only volume integrals which allow us to use Gauss' theorem to say something about a surface integral. You may want to elaborate.

Comment: Its simply so, that the euclidan volume $dr\wedge  r\ d \theta \wedge r \sin \theta \ d\phi $ can be separated to $ r^2 dr \wedge \sin \theta \ d \theta \wedge d \phi=r^2 dr \wedge d z \wedge d \phi $ for spherical  or cylindrical representations. Freely  changing local bases is the great advance of exterior calculus in interplay with Fubini and partial integrations and volume integrands in vector analysis are local limits of surface integrals by defintion.

Answer (score 2):

At least its easy to integrate the form in spherical coordinates

$$x \to \cos \phi \sin \theta , \ y \to \sin \phi \sin \theta,  \
 z \to   \cos \theta$$

$$\{\text{dx}\to \text{d$\theta $} \ \cos (\theta )\ \cos (\phi )-\text{d$\phi $} \  \sin (\theta ) \ \sin (\phi ),\ \ \text{dy}\to \text{d$\theta $} \ \cos (\theta ) \ \sin (\phi )+\text{d$\phi $} \ \sin (\theta ) \ \cos (\phi ),\ \ \text{dz}\to -\text{d$\theta $} \  \sin (\theta )\}$$

The resulting 2-form is (typo corrected)

$$\sin (\theta ) \text{d$\theta $}\wedge \text{d$\phi $} \left(\frac{1}{4} \sin ^4(\theta ) (\cos (4 \phi )+3)+\cos ^4(\theta )\right)$$

My result is $\frac{6 \pi }{5}$